# SQL Data Sync portal doesn't see any tables or schemas

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

I was trying out the new Data Sync from the new portal. But when I try to add the sync rules (which I think it's required to start syncing) doesn't load the schemas and tables.

I created the tables in both databases, just for testing, but nothing change.

Anyone is using the Azure Data Syn in the new portal or already saw this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renan,

this has been answered in your other forum post already.

It's a case of the tables not having Primary Keys.

Comment: It's not my post, but THANKS!

Comment: sorry, it though it's the same one as this :): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fil/ssdsgetstarted/thread/c1d4c82b-12ef-425a-a73d-7d4ee6c7c494